# area of part of Archimedes's spiral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the area of region inside the "first loop" of the Archimedes spiral (that is, the spiral for $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$) and to the left of the  $y$-axis.

The area the question wants is between $\theta = \pi/2$ and $\theta = 3\pi/2$ for the graph $r=\theta$. Therefore, I computed the integral $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \theta \,d\theta = \pi^2$. I even checked it with a graphing calculator to make sure that the integral was computed correctly. However, apparently, this is not a correct answer. Could someone help me see why?

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote the area as $\int\theta\ d\theta$? Are you familiar with double integrals?

Comment: Isn't the area element  $r dr d\theta$ in polar?

Comment: The integral is $\int \int r d\theta dr = \frac{1}{2}\int \theta^2 d\theta$, you forgot to integrate $r$ first from zero to $\theta$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that the area element in polar coordinates is given by $r\ dr\ d\theta$. For any value of $\theta,r$ ranges from $0\to\theta$. Further, $\theta$ ranges from $\pi/2\to3\pi/2$.

The answer is $$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_0^\theta r\ dr\ d\theta=\frac{13\pi^3}{24}$$

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 6):

The integral for finding the area in polar coordinate is different from what you have.

Please use the correct formula and you will get the correct answer.

$$ A = (1/2) \int  r^2  d\theta $$ where in your case $ r=\theta $

Comment: An extra $\pi$ there

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, now it is correct.